# AWS Waf: Allow your own domain in AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet#GenericRFI_BODY

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, acl, web-application-firewall

Currently my WAF is blocking requests that contain a reference to a resource on my own domain. For example the body of a request can look like :

```
{
  "myPicture": "https://example.com/user1/profilePicture",
  "username": "user1"
}
```

I could ignore violations of GenericRFI_BODY but this would expose me to links hosted anywhere.

Can I not add an extra rule which allows requests that contain a link to my domain.

For first the AWS common rules set which includes GenericRFI_Body:

```
          Priority: 0
          Statement:
            ManagedRuleGroupStatement:
              VendorName: AWS
              Name: AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet
          OverrideAction:
            None: {}
          VisibilityConfig:
            SampledRequestsEnabled: true
            CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
            MetricName: AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet
```

And then something in the like this to allow links to my own domain:

```
        - Name: AllowOwnDomain
          Priority: 1
          Statement:
            AndStatement:
              Statements:
                - LabelMatchStatement:
                    Scope: LABEL
                    Key: awswaf:managed:aws:common-rule-set:signal:genericRFI_BODY
                - NotStatement:
                    Statement:
                      ByteMatchStatement:
                        FieldToMatch:
                          JsonBody:
                            MatchPattern: "https://example.com"
                            MatchScope: VALUE
                        PositionalConstraint: CONTAINS
                        TextTransformations:
                          - Priority: 0
                            Type: NONE
          Action:
            Block: {}
          VisibilityConfig:
            SampledRequestsEnabled: true
            CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
            MetricName: AllowOwnDomain
```

The above is not working.
How can something like this be done?
(Keep the Generic_RFIBody statement in place but create an exception for your own domain)